# Why Facebook can send push notification to chrome when I don't have any facebook app/url opened?

Tags: google-chrome

First, I have searched this question but all the answers are not answering the question, instead, they provide Push Notification tutorial/doc links.

When I search how to disable facebook push notifications, all the answers are about disable it in the settings --> content settings --> notifications.

All of this does not explain why Facebook can send push notification to chrome at the background when I am not accessing facebook.com and don't install anything manually.

If there are some hidden facebook workers installed to my chrome, then where is it? Instead of blocking the facebook notification link, the true solution should be removing the worker (or extension, or a script, or a cookie, or a storage etc).

Can anyone just tell me where the background hidden facebook worker is? Thank you very much.

Comment: Is the content settings not working?

Comment: @JoshLee Sorry, my question is nothing related to `content settings` --> `notifications`.